# Android: Efficient way to compress Bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap, android-bitmap, image-compression

Is there a decent way to compress a Bitmap without re-scaling it without eating too much memory that cause OOM?

```
Bitmap compressedImageFile;
try {
    compressedImageFile = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), fileUri);
    
    //Converting bitmap to array stream
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    //Decreasing the quality for thumbnail
    compressedImageFile.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 50, byteArrayOutputStream);
    
    //Convert Bitmap to Byte array
    byte[] thumbData = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();

    ...
```

`byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray()` is causing OOM, this can be avoid by reducing the bitmap size in a half but probably there is a more decent approach?

This is where I am using it
[image]

Comment: Compress the image to a `FileOutputStream` rather than a `ByteArrayOutputStream`.

Comment: @CommonsWare can we use that with Uri?

Comment: That portion of your code (`MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap`) does not change.

Comment: @CommonsWare I added a detail to my question and I do not know where `FileOutputStream` can be use.

Comment: @CommonsWare sorry to disturb you but can you provide a complete answer? Thanks a lot